# Separate compilation in C++

Tags: c++, compilation

Suppose you are creating a class with multiple .cpp files (which each contain the implementation of a member function) and have the class' declaration in a .h file. Also, each .cpp file includes the .h file via the include directive.

I was told that if you change the implementation of any of the member functions (.cpp files) that you will have to recompile every .cpp file in order to run the program. That is, if I had 5 member functions (each implemented in a .cpp file) and I changed the implementation of 1 of the .cpp files I would have to compile the 1 .cpp file I changed AND the 4 other .cpp files I didn't change in order to correctly run my program.

My question, if the previous statement is true, is why is the statement is true? Any insight on this concept would be helpful.

Comment: See this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188101/recompile-after-base-class-change/9188135) related to base classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's false. If there is no change to a particular implementation file, no change to header files it includes, and no changes to the environment or compiler options, there is absolutely no need to recompile it. Everything that affects the compilation of that file hasn't changed.

In fact, you can compile each of the files without even having any of the others at all. Then you can link all the compiled files together without all the implementation files ever having been in the same place.

Comment: header files are also C++ files... using the term "implementation" file, or even a list of common extensions ala .cc/.cpp, is less confusing....

Answer (score 3):

The statement is false. In fact, the whole reason `make` (and similar) exist is because it's false -- they minimize the time/effort to rebuild an application by keeping track of which source files have changed, and re-creating only the object files that depend on source files that have changed. Object files that are up to date are simply left alone.

Once all the object files are up to date, they're linked together to produce the final executable (and, again, this is normally only done when/if at least one object file is newer than the current executable).

Of course, it's also possible to use `make` for jobs unrelated to compiling and linking, but that is almost certainly the use to which they're most commonly put, and (at least most of) the reason they were invented (the only obvious change being that they were originally used primarily for C source code rather than C++, but in this respect the two are nearly indistinguishable).

The only obvious difference between the two is that when/if you use templates, you typically end up putting a lot of code into headers. In this case, changing a header forces re-compiling all the code that includes that header, which is often a lot. With C code and/or non-template C++ code, you put most of the code into a source file, so you only need to re-compile other files if you change the *interface* to the code (which would typically change the header), but only that file needs to be re-compiled if you restrict your changes to the implementation without changing the interface.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, though of course private and protected members, inline functions etc. are other examples of "implementation" often found in headers.  pmcs's answer lists some links about those....

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the statement is false. However, there do exist interesting complications regarding modified source files, source dependencies, and recompilation. The most helpful discussions of this are, unsurprisingly, given in a series of Guru of the Week posts from Herb Sutter, in which he discusses dependency isolation and the Pimpl idiom:

[Compilation Firewalls](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/024.htm)

[The Fast Pimpl Idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm)

[The Joy of Pimpls](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill05.htm)

This stuff appears esoteric to almost everyone the first time they see it but the Pimpl idiom turns out to be *astonishingly* useful in practice.